# mongoose list collections of a specific database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use the following code to list the collections of the current database, but how to list the collections of another one?

```
  mongoose.connection.db
    .listCollections()
    .toArray()
    .then(coll => console.log({ coll }));
```

Answer (score 0):

At one time you can see collections regarding only one Database. So if you need to list another database collections, you just need to change the corresponding DB name in the DB connection function. (Simply you can change the connection URL DB name)

**Note**:- If particular DB has different username and password than current DB, you need to change it on the connection URL as well.

Comment: thanks @kmkm, please give me the code. and should I reconnect to the database again to change the current database?